# Windows Phone 8. autocapitalize not supported in IE10

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, internet-explorer-10

For iOS & Android, their webkit browsers support the autocapitalize property on an input element to control whether the first word of a sentence is capitalized.

On Windows Phone 8 IE10 this doesn't work. Does anyone know of an equivalent way of achieving auto-capitalization in IE10 on Windows Phone?

Comment: What input type are you using?

Comment: I'm using type="text".

Comment: I believe `autocapitalize` is Apple-Specific tag. You can try CSS's `text-transform: capitalize`. Mobile IE supports that.

Comment: AFAIK `autocapitalize` only capitalizes the first word of a sentence? Using `text-transform` would make all words capitalized, also it would be just a visual effect, the actual value would still be in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not supported then you have to do it on your own via JavaScript. Assuming key and/or change events are being fired by the mobile browser, you could simply hook into these events and transform the input value accordingly.

Here's an example that transforms the very first letter which may be preceded by whitespace, and the first letter after a period that is followed by whitespace:

```js
$('[autocapitalize="on"]').on('change keyup', function(event)
{
    var selectionStart = event.target.selectionStart;
    var selectionEnd = event.target.selectionEnd; 

    var element = $(this);
    element.val(element.val().replace(/^\s*(.)|\.\s+(.)/g, function(letter)
    {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    }));

    event.target.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rbpCC/)

Comment: Many thanks for that elegant solution. There are a couple of problems with this approach though. 1) There is no way for the user to force a lowercase character after a period (which autocapitalize does on iOS). 2) Only a minor one this but the soft keyboard doesn't indicate that the next typed letter will be capitalised (by highlighting the shift key). I may still use this approach though because it's still an improvement for the user, even allowing for the 2 problems listed. Once again, many thanks.